# Finding Cook's Distance within subjects in R

Tags: r

I have a data set with 700 different accounts. Each account has multiple lines with an x and y variable. So in total about 26000 lines of data. I am trying to find 'influential' points that are associated within the specific accounts. I have used lmlist function to get the estimated coefficients to a GLR.

`model3 <- lmList(y ~ x | grp, data = dat)`

I have tried to use the influence and then the CookD function, but I believe it's not compatible with the lmList.

I know that the cook functions work with lmer, but lmer throws a warning about failure to converge with my dataset:

`model1 <- lmer(y ~ x + (x | grp) , data = dat)`

I have read many posts on this but still confused. I wish I had a little more expertise to write what I am trying to achieve. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer help you at all? Or do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to consider is that `nlme::lmList` returns a `list` object, so you have to use list methods on it.

Two ways to do this, using a made up model on the `iris` data. The first way estimates separate models for each group, whilst the second way fits a multilevel model, with observations nested within groups.

First, using `lmList` from `nlme` and `cooks.distance` from `base` R:

```
library(nlme)

# run the models and store them
modlist <- lmList(object = Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length | Species, data = iris)

# see the results 
summary(modlist)
```

This returns:

```
Call:
  Model: Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length | Species 
   Data: iris 

Coefficients:
   (Intercept) 
            Estimate Std. Error   t value  Pr(>|t|)
setosa     0.8030518  0.5310388 1.5122280 0.1326674
versicolor 0.1851155  0.4305590 0.4299423 0.6678803
virginica  0.6104680  0.3882233 1.5724662 0.1180371
   Sepal.Length 
            Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
setosa     0.1316317 0.10582369  1.243877 2.155658e-01
versicolor 0.6864698 0.07226626  9.499174 6.483105e-17
virginica  0.7500808 0.05866167 12.786556 1.714921e-25

Residual standard error: 0.2611123 on 144 degrees of freedom
```

Now get the Cook's distance:

```
cooks1 <- lapply(modlist, cooks.distance)
```

Second, using `lmList` from `lme4` and `CookD` from `predictmeans`:

```
library(predictmeans)
# this loads lme4 as a required package

# run the models and store them
modlist2 <- lmer(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + (1 | Species), data = iris)

# see the results
summary(modlist2)
```

This returns:

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + (1 | Species)
   Data: iris

REML criterion at convergence: 69.3

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.71305 -0.62672  0.02935  0.61922  2.83011 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Species  (Intercept) 2.52912  1.5903  
 Residual             0.07984  0.2826  
Number of obs: 150, groups:  Species, 3

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   0.05252    0.95576   0.055
Sepal.Length  0.63414    0.04525  14.014

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
Sepal.Lngth -0.277
```

Get the Cook's distance and associated plot:

```
cooks2 <- CookD(model = modlist2)
```

`CookD` also throws up some failure to converge warnings here, but the plot seems ok and influential points stand out quite clearly.