# how to remove outliers from cooks distance in R

Tags: r

I am writing a generic function which takes dataframe and column name and return the clean dataframe without outliers in R

```
cooks_dist <- function(dataframe,column){
  dataframe <- dataframe %>%  select_if(dataframe,is.numeric)
  mod <- lm(column ~ ., data=dataframe)
  cooksd <- cooks.distance(mod)

  influential <- as.numeric(names(cooksd)[(cooksd > 4*mean(cooksd,na.rm=T))])  # influential row numbers

  final <- dataframe[-influential,]

  return(final)

}
```

But,when I run this function it says `Error: Can't convert a list to function`

Data can be found at

`http://ucanalytics.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Regression-Clean-Data.csv`

Comment: The notion that removing influentials would somehow "clean" data is a perversion of good data handling. If this is what your current teachers are advising, you should seek a more reputable source of instruction,

Comment: You can look at one example in the link below. It uses R to remove outliers based on cooks' distance. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164099/removing-outliers-based-on-cooks-distance-in-r-language

Answer (score 2):

The error originated from `dplyr::select_if()`. I believe you want a subset of all numeric columns so you alternatively could create a subset with `sapply()`. *Note:* As your `lm()` line produced errors, I`ve inserted the minimal model instead.

So I think you want this:

```
cooks_dist <- function(dataframe, column){
  dataframe <- dataframe[, sapply(dataframe, is.numeric)]
  mod <- lm(dataframe[, column] ~ 1, data = dataframe)
  cooksd <- cooks.distance(mod)
  influential <- as.numeric(names(cooksd)[(cooksd > 4 * mean(cooksd, na.rm = TRUE))])
  final <- dataframe[-influential, ]
  return(final)
}

df1 <- cooks_dist(df1, 4)
```

### *Yields:*

```
> head(df1)
  X Observation Dist_Taxi Dist_Market Dist_Hospital Carpet Builtup Rainfall House_Price
2 2           2      8294        8186         12694   1461    1752      210     3982000
3 3           3     11001       14399         16991   1340    1609      720     5401000
4 4           4      8301       11188         12289   1451    1748      620     5373000
5 5           5     10510       12629         13921   1770    2111      450     4662000
7 7           7     13153       11869         17811   1542    1858     1030     7224000
8 8           8      5882        9948         13315   1261    1507     1020     3772000
```

Comment: in `lm()` when I keep all the variables instead of only `1` in your answer,it does not remove any outliers. Why is that so?

Comment: I believe you might find further help e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737362/6574038

Answer (score 0):

I used this code, with threshold for cooks as 4/n:

```
orig.mod <- lm(Outcome ~ Exposure, data=origdf)

origdf$cooksd <- cooks.distance(orig.mod)

origdf$cookyn <- ifelse(origdf$cooksd < 4/nrow(orig.dat), "keep","no")

minus.df <-subset(origdf, cookyn=="keep")

newmod.minuscooks <- lm(Outcome ~ Exposure, data=minus.df)
```

Comment: Does __orig.dat__ == __origdf__ in that 3rd line of code??